# How to add a property to an object returned by Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I am doing the following Query in doctrine:

```
    $result = $conductores
            ->select('c.id, c.runFormateado, c.nombres, c.apellidos, c.requisitosWebcontrol, e.nombre as empresa, c.createdAt, c.updatedAt')
            ->innerJoin('c.empresa', 'e', 'ON')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

I need to modify each record of that result set to have 2 more properties that I will use later.

I tried by adding "null as new_property" in the select method call but doctrine shows an error.

How can I do it?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$result = $conductores
        ->select('c.id, c.runFormateado, c.nombres, c.apellidos, c.requisitosWebcontrol, e.nombre as empresa, c.createdAt, c.updatedAt, \'\' as new_property_1, \'\' as new_property_2')
        ->innerJoin('c.empresa', 'e', 'ON')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

You can try this using MySQL directly in your database, to see how this works. 
Example: Assuming you have a User table

```
select Id, FirstName, LastName, '' as new_colum_1, '' as new_column_2
from Users;
```

I hope this works for you.